# Should I add water to my homemade orange juice?

Tags: juice, oranges

I am considering adding water to my fresh-squeezed orange juice. The purpose is mainly to obtain a juice that is less acidic and easier to digest. I suppose there are pros and cons for mixing water/orange juice and I am wondering if mixing them is a good idea.

1. Does water affect the juice's nutritive or conservative value?
2. If adding water is a good idea, what kind of water should I add (mineral? boiled?) and in what proportion (50/50?)?

Comment: I've never tried watering down orange juice, but I've thought about testing the limits on where a person might consider something to be lemonade vs. acidulated water.

Comment: And I should mention that when I was a kid, my mom cut the acidity by blending orange & apple juices to give us.

Comment: You could also try adding adding a small amount of basic substance (baking soda comes to mind) to counteract the acid in the orange juice. I'm not posting this as an answer because I've never tried it personally, and I can imagine it tasting pretty terrible. Try at your own risk.

Comment: Hello ppr, I'm afraid your question is not really suited for the site. The "nutrition value" part is off topic. When you take that out, there are no criteria on which to decide whether to do it or not. Basically, you'd be asking "which is tastier, full strength juice or diluted juice" and this is a matter of personal preference, different people prefer it differently.

Comment: (In other words, if your question is not about nutrition, it's probably primarily opinion-based.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Does water affect the conservative value:**

I doubt adding water would noticeably hurt the conservation value, but you could always add it to an actual serving, instead of pre-mixing it.

**Does water affect the nutritive value:**

It would of course go down *per serving*. Less juice in the same serving means less of the nutritional / healthy stuff in said serving.

**What kind of water:**

I would just use plain water. Mineral will dilute the taste even more than regular water, and actually create a different kind of drink.

**My take on it, and thus a personal con:**

Don't do it, unless you really can't take the acidity of fresh orange juice. The cheaper hotels tend to do it to create more bang for the buck (from their perspective), and I absolutely hate it. The taste suffers, and, for me less important, the nutritional value suffers. To my mind, orange juice with water lacks everything that makes orange juice delicious.